# Horizontal vs Vertical Scaling on Heroku NodeJS App

Tags: heroku

I have a single NodeJS web process that is a simple api server. This process hits memory limits before CPU limits. What is the proper way to scale this app on Heroku? Do I add more dynos or switch to a larger sized dyno?